# In C, a pointer to a structure that needs to access a list of byte pointers

Tags: c

First off, sorry for the title, it was hard to come up with a description.  I am attempting to create a structure that will access a peripheral that has quite of few internal registers that are controlled by 3 address lines.  So I have the following structure definition:

```
typedef struct {
  union {
    unsigned char  *reg0aPtr;
    unsigned char  *reg0bPtr;
  } RegsAddrOffset0;

  union {
    unsigned char  *reg1aPtr;
    unsigned char  *reg1bPtr;
  } RegsAddrOffset1;

  ...

  union {
    unsigned char  *reg7aPtr;
    unsigned char  *reg7bPtr;
  } RegsAddrOffset7;
} DeviceRegMap;
```

Then if I declare a variable as so

```
DeviceRegMap  *uartRegMap = (DeviceRegMap *)(0xD0000000);
```

Now, if I try to to use the uartRegMap variable to access the memory mapped registers I thought I would see that *(uartRegMap->RegsAddrOffset0.reg0aPtr) would read the data from address 0xD0000000, which is does.  If I use *(uartRegMap->RegsAddrOffset1.reg1bPtr) I thought I would access 0xD0000001, but it is actually accesses address 0xD0000004.  Since the processor is 32-bit the natural alignment is 4-bytes.  I am thinking since the size of a pointer is an int which in this case is 32-bits this is the reason why I am accessing on 4-byte address ranges (e.g., 0xD0000000, 0xD0000004, 0xD0000008, etc).

If I declared an instance of the DeviceRegMap datatype I would expect the following initialization:

```
DeviceRegMap uartRegMap = {
  (unsigned char  *)0xD0000000,
  (unsigned char  *)0xD0000001,
  ...
  (unsigned char  *)0xD0000007,
};
```

Then if I wanted to access address 0xD0000007 then I would use *(uartRegMap.RegsAddrOffset7.reg7bPtr)

The question is why is the pointer to the DeviceRegMap data type access memory on 4-byte alignments (e.g., 0xD0000000, 0xD0000004, etc) instead of byte alignments (e.g., 0xD0000000, 0xD0000001, etc).  With regards to the toolset I am using Wind River diab compiler.  Thanks.

Mark

EDIT: Based upon abelenky's comment

Comment: What is your question?  "I just want to make sure I understand what is going on." is NOT a question.

Comment: Why are you using a `union` of two items of the same type?

Comment: Just to add some additional insight to what is going.  The code was developed by another engineer which I inherited for a UART device driver.  The UART has about 21 different registers which are access via three address lines which are memory mapped.  The unions are really not needed, as people have pointed out, but they add clarity to the reading of the code.  For instance, at an offset of 0x00 there is the TX and RX Holding Registers along with some other registers.  So the code uses ->RHR or ->THR which helps readability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to access the byte-sized parts of a memory-mapped register, do the following:

```
struct DeviceRegMap {
  volatile unsigned char byte0;
  volatile unsigned char byte1;
  volatile unsigned char byte2;
  volatile unsigned char byte3;
};

static struct DeviceRegMap *device = (struct DeviceRegMap *)(0xD0000000);
```

Now `device->byte0` points to `0xD0000000`, and `device->byte3` points to `0xD00000003`. Is that what you want?

Comment: Roland, I think that should work.  I will have to wait until I get to work to test it out on the hardware. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Most compilers have a way to indicate that a structure should be packed tightly, without padding for alignment purposes.

I'm not familiar with your compiler, but explore the documentation for something like

```
#pragma pack
```

before your structure definition.